# Print to zebra zt400 with print server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cups, zebra-printer

we want to print to a zebra printer attached to a printer server hardware.

We have installed cups on a ubuntu machine and setup the ip and port of the print server but when we send something to print the printer is not responding. The printer is add as ipp/http protocol.

If I use the command

lpr -P Zebra -o raw file.txt

Nothing comes out of the printer but of I use the command without the -o raw parameter prints the zpl commands instead of the label.

Can somebody help me to figure out the right setup for the cups server. I can not change the setup or attached the printer to the ubuntu machine.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Is the IP of the printer in the same range as the network card you have installed? The first three number should be the same. Else you have to route the IP of the printer explicitly to that interface.

Comment: The printer does not have the ip, the ip is on the print server hardware, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question

I could send zpl commands to the printer attached to this print server, adding it to my cups server as socket://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9101 the trick was to add the 9101 port which is the first port of the print server.

Hope to help somebody with similar issue.